# Neo4j OGM @Properties which entry types are supported?

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I try to persist the following entity into a Neo4J database with Spring Data Neo4j (SDN). The entity has a property `java.util.Map<CustomEnum,Instant>`.

Check the following example code:

```java
public enum CustomEnum {
  TREE, LEAVE, FLOWER;
}
```

```java
@NodeEntity
public class ExampleEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  // omitted simple properties of type String

  @Properties(allowCast = true)
  Map<CustomEnum,Instant> myMapProperty = new HashMap<>();
}
```

The problem I have is, that Neo4J OGM complains that it is not able to persist the `Map<CustomEnum, Instant>` because of an unsupported Type.

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException:
```

I located the source of the exception to come from the `MapCompositeConverter`: [Link to Github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/c16e8f0b587f3052652d97b77cf3bc8df74664ee/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/typeconversion/MapCompositeConverter.java#L111).

If my analysis is correct, the core issue lies in OGM only allowing the default Cypher types as defined in `AbstractConfigurableDriver`: [Link to Github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/c16e8f0b587f3052652d97b77cf3bc8df74664ee/api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/driver/AbstractConfigurableDriver.java#L71)

This would be a different behavior as explained in the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity:dynamic-properties), which explains that many native Java types (including the temporal types `Instant, LocalDate, Period`) should be supported.

I would be very happy about a pointer in the right direction.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-Data-Neo4j supports basic types like String, Integer, Long, and so on.
Some more complex types like Instant and Date are also supported, but only because Spring-Data-Neo4j uses OGM, which comes with a set of `AttributeConverters`, that implicitly convert Instant and Date to String.
You can define your own converters and put them on your `@Property` attributes to use this converter.

For example you can build the `FooToStringConverter` as follows:

```
public class FooToStringConverter implements AttributConverter<Foo, String>{
  String convertToDatabaseColumn(Foo foo){
    return foo.toString();
  }

  Foo convertToEntityAttribute(String fooString){
    return Foo.fromString();
  }
```

}

And then annotate your entity as

```
@Property
@Converter(converter=FooToStringConverter.class)
private Foo foo;
```

However the extensive use of Converters kinda kills the Traverse-The-Graph advantage you get with Neo4j since now you need to use indexes.
It'll work that way, but maybe you need to overthink the architecture to use more nodes instead of embedded compley properties.

Hope this helps.